# Meaning of “put someone’s heads on backwards”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I’ve run into the following sentences today and don’t understand their meanings. Could you explain?

- I am almost too embarrassed to post this on here, but I **put my heads
  on backwards.**
- discombobulated meaning: When you're discombobulated, you've totally
  fallen apart, like someone **put your head on backwards.**

Comment: The juxtaposition of the two example sentences clearly explains the meaning of *put head on backwards*. Unless you don't understand what [*discombobulated*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discombobulated) means—making this a circular-type of definition?

Comment: This usage has effectively ***zero*** currency outside the context of a song by [The Sonics](https://genius.com/The-sonics-you-got-your-head-on-backwards-lyrics) – *You Got Your Head on Backwards Lyrics*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Your head is on backwards' is a figurative way of saying that you're confused. If your head were on backwards you would only see behind you and you wouldn't know where you were going. You wouldn't know how to make forward progress. A person who is confused is acting the same way they would if their head were on backwards.

Comment: Late better than never.